# ¿Cómo mostrar datos completos de una consulta MySQL en wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Por medio de `$wpdb` estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos de WordPress para que me muestre los datos en un `<input>` de tal forma que el usuario luego pueda modificaros.

Mi problema viene cuando los datos no se visualizan correctamente ya que en un `<input>` donde se deberían mostrar varias palabras solo se muestra la primera de ellas.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de la dirección "la breña" me muestra solo "la" y lo mismo en todos los campos.

SQL USADO EN EL `$wpdb`:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'");
```

HTML donde muestro los datos:

```
'<div>Dirección: <input type="text" name="Direccion" value=' .$datos[0]->direccion. '>
Código Postal: <input type="text" name="CodigoPostal" value=' .$datos[0]->codigopostal. '>
Población: <input type="text" name="Poblacion" value=' .$datos[0]->poblacion. '>
Provincia: <input type="text" name="Provincia" value=' .$datos[0]->provincia. '>
Teléfono móvíl: <input type="text" name="TelefonoMovil" value=' .$datos[0]->telefonomovil. '>
Teléfono fijo: <input type="text" name="TelefonoFijo" value=' .$datos[0]->telefonofijo. '>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value=' .$datos[0]->email. '></div>'
```

Con esto muestro los datos sin problema ***SIEMPRE QUE SOLO SEA UNA PALABRA***. Cuando ya es más de una me da solo la primera y necesito que muestre todas.

Comment: Tu problema está en que ni estás escapando con `htmlspecialchars` los datos obtenidos de la base de datos ni estás entrecomillando los atributos de las etiquetas HTML. Voy a redactarte una respuesta con la forma correcta de hacer el trabajo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás cometiendo un error grave al generar el código HTML al no entrecomillar los atributos de la etiqueta HTML:

```
$html = '<div>
  Dirección:
  <input type="text" name="Direccion" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->direccion) . '">
  Código Postal:
  <input type="text" name="CodigoPostal" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->codigopostal) . '">
  Población:
  <input type="text" name="Poblacion" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->poblacion) . '">
  Provincia:
  <input type="text" name="Provincia" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->provincia) . '">
  Teléfono móvil:
  <input type="text" name="TelefonoMovil" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->telefonomovil) . '">
  Teléfono fijo:
  <input type="text" name="TelefonoFijo" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->telefonofijo) . '">
  E-mail:
  <input type="text" name="email" value="' . htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->email. '">
</div>';
```

En vez de rellenar cadenas de caracteres puedes realizar el envío al navegador con HTML y usar `<?= .. ?>` para evitar la concatenación de variables:

```
<input type="text" name="email"
  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($datos[0]->email ?>" />
```

Además te aconsejaré dos cambios más:

- Debes escapar siempre las cadenas de texto enviadas al navegador.
- Deberías usar consultas preparadas.

La primera recomendación ya te la he aplicado en la respuesta usando [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

La segunda recomendación requiere que cambies tu código a [consultas preparadas de wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/):

```
<?php
/* Preparamos la consulta */
$consulta = $wpdb->prepare(
  "
    SELECT *
    FROM nikkiclub
    WHERE numerotarjeta = %s AND Clavetarjeta = %s
  ",
  [
    $NumTarjetaFidelizacion,
    $ClaveTarjeta,
  ]
);
/* Obtenemos los resultados */
$resultado = $wpdb->get_results($consulta);
```

Comment: muchas gracias lo probare ya mismo a ver si me funciona, el tema de las consultas preparadas lo estaba preparando ahora, primero lo hice ne modo chapuza para ver si funcionaba y luego ir mejorando el codigo, muchas gracias

Comment: Un placer, espero que te sea de ayuda el código de ejemplo.

Comment: me ha venido de perlas justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias